# Vertical scrollbar appears for unknown reason

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

What causes vertical scrollbar to appear here? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QGByOQ?editors=1100

As I suggest, `.container` is `100%` height of `body`, body inherits `html`, `html` is 100% of the `viewport`, hence every `.chart` should fit perfectly as it's height is half of the `.container`'s. Nevertheless a y-scrollbar appears. What's the behavior behind this?

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="chart1"></div>
        <div class="chart1"></div>
        <div class="chart1"></div>
        <div class="chart1"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

css:

```
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 5px dashed black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.chart1 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: your codepen do not show a vertical scrollbar... you have already solved the issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to the red border of the container. Use CSS `calc()` function, like:

```
.chart1 {
  height: calc(100% - 1px); /* 1px for the extra border */
}
```

Have a look at the snippet below:

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 5px dashed black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.chart1 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  height: calc(50% - 1px);
  border: 1px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="chart1"></div>
  <div class="chart1"></div>
  <div class="chart1"></div>
  <div class="chart1"></div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: i think it should be -2 pixel for every divs. becaust top and bottom border